# Prove whether the function $\left\lfloor\frac{\left\lceil x\right\rceil}{2}\right\rfloor: \mathbb{Z}→\mathbb{Z}$ is surjective, injective or bijective

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So my logic to this up until now has been that for any $x$ the function $\left\lfloor\frac{\lceil x\rceil}{2}\right\rfloor$ will return an integer that is an element of $\mathbb Z$. Thus since you can map any $x$ in the domain to any y in the co-domain it is surjective.

Now I'm not sure if this counts as a full proof, and whether the function is injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\lceil x\rceil=x$ for all integers $x$, so really the function is just $\lfloor x/2\rfloor$. Choose $x=2,3$, and the value of the function is $1$ at both of these points, hence the function is not injective. But to get an integer $y$ it always suffices to choose the integer $x=2y$ as the input, since $\lfloor 2y/2\rfloor =\lfloor y\rfloor = y$, hence it is surjective.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the great response. Your last sentence confuses me a little though, how do you get x = 2y?  is that just from ⌊x/2⌋ = y and then you just solved for y? if so how does that work when working with a floor.

Comment: @Brownie he noticed that $x=2y$ when plugged into the function gives us $y$ for every $y\in\mathbb{Z}$, and in that way you can get any integer desired

Comment: That makes a lot  more sense, so it was just the fact that 2y/2 simplifies to y

Answer (score 2):

It is surjective but your proof is not complete. For any $y$ in the co-domain, you must produce an $x$ such that $\lfloor \lceil x \rceil / 2 \rfloor = y$.

To check injectivity, ask yourself if it is possible for $x \ne x'$ and $\lfloor \lceil x \rceil / 2 \rfloor = \lfloor \lceil x' \rceil / 2 \rfloor$ to occur. If it is, then it is not injective; if it is impossible, it is injective.